node.js http-server example - need explanation on subscription way
I'm a newbie to JavaScript and Node.js, learning some stuff.
I came across this example of an HTTP server at nodejs.org site: https://nodejs.org/en/learn/modules/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction#put-it-all-together
There is something there that I don't understand.
the code is:

http
  .createServer((request, response) => {
    const { headers, method, url } = request;
    let body = [];
    request
      .on('error', err => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .on('data', chunk => {
        body.push(chunk);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        // BEGINNING OF NEW STUFF

        response.on('error', err => {
          console.error(err);
        });

        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        // Note: the 2 lines above could be replaced with this next one:
        // response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

        const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };

        response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
        response.end();
        // Note: the 2 lines above could be replaced with this next one:
        // response.end(JSON.stringify(responseBody))

        // END OF NEW STUFF
      });
  })
  .listen(8080);


The request object is of type EventEmitter, so it knows to emit events.
The callback passed to the createServer method subscribes to 'error' event.
I don't understand when is the event emitted.

I mean the request is probably being processed prior to running the callback (as the line const { headers, method, url } = request; shows.
so when the request was processed, we did not subscribe yet to the event.
How does the callback get the on('error') handler called?
Alternatively, if the code contained a line like request.processData() (or something similar) after the subscription, it would also explain how things work, but there is not such call.
We supply a callback which is called on error, and subscribe to errors in the middle of the code. what is triggering the publish of the error event here? and when is it triggered?
I checked it works by running the command (which waits as the content-length is greater than the body size)

curl -X POST -d "hello all" -H "Content-Length: 33"
http://localhost:8080/abc

and stopping it using Ctrl+C, this causes the server side to write an error, about the connection being aborted.

Can you clarify the question? What kind of error is triggered or the thing in whole? In (request, response) => callback a request is about to start, this is the last point we can affect it and set up a listener.

I've updated my question and added a description of how the server generates an error. My question is about the subscription to the error event. As the subscription is done after the callback starts to run, which code emits the event?

It's a callback that starts to run, not a request itself. As noted in the previous comment, a request isn't started at the time when you call request.on('error', and error event will be triggered asynchronously at later point. This is regular node approach to avoid race conditions in a situation like this one, it's implemented internally like https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processnexttickcallback-args .
